# Some questions about LDAP

Tags: ldap, centos6

Since 7 years I'm working with LDAP but when times change the company who is using the software wants it to be LDAPS.

I'm currently running on Centos 6 (will be 7 this year).

The company provided me with an certificate in PFX format and a password. How do I install a PFX on Centos 6, and how do I get LDAPS working? Do I need OpenLDAP (and how to config that)?

I only need to check if a user + pass is in the AD, I don't need anything more from the AD.

Comment: LDAPS is just LDAP over SSL. You only have to install the private key and certificate into the existing LDAP server's configuration. Off topic.

Comment: Certificate is installed, virtual host has been added / modified, made a .crt and .pem out of the PFX.
If I try to bind the same way but with ldaps:// it doesn't work.
Do I have to include the certificate (and how) before binding?

Comment: Try looking at: https://serverfault.com/a/323569/141289